# div inside a div vertical in a side bar using css

Tags: html, css

i have a page that i need to have a left side bar that this one contain a a title under that an image under that a text under that a list  how can i do this i tried the  relative position and absolute but it did not work

what i need is a div inside a div means the leftsidebar  is a div that include the the title , image, text, list.

can anyone help me ?????

this what i tried to do to the image

```
.leftsideBar h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.leftsideBar {
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border:5px solid #FF0000;
    position:relative;

}
#profileImage{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    border:5px solid #0000FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPrUa/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

html:

```
    <div class="leftsideBar">
        <h2>title</h2>
        <img src="" height="100" width="100"/>
        <ul>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
            <li>test1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.leftsideBar h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.leftsideBar {
    float: left;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    border:5px solid #FF0000;
    position:relative;
}
#profileImage{
    border:5px solid #0000FF;
}
```

here it is another option with the text next to the image -> [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/zPrUa/2/)

Comment: it depends what you are trying to achieve. i prefer to have as less elements as possible, so avoid any unnecessary wrapping. ps: if my answer answers your question, i would appreciate if you upvote or mark as answer.

Comment: i will upvote  sir  i am trying to have a left bar as the one of the facebook that include a picture and texts and lists